# Apple Mach-O Linker Error ADAL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, adal

I have installed the ADAL 2.4.1 referring https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc in my xcode project using Cocoapods. The library seems to have successfully added to my xcode project. But I am now unable to build the project and keep on getting the `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADAuthenticationContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in KSAPIController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**EDIT**

I fixed The first issue by doing

```
TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class
```

But now I get a different error

`Lexical or Preprocessor issue`

```
ADAuthenticationSettings.h file not found in ADAuthenticationContext.m
```